# Unable to set IBOutlet correctly in xib file Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib, outlet

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to implement a Native google ad inside my Flutter project. I followed step by step documentation to create the native ad in swift but now I'm not able to link the outlet with my factory.

I tried to link the view by drag it to the factory class :

[image]

But I'm getting this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x28140cd90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key advertiserView.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It seems that the first outlet is causing crash because it doesn't recognize it.

According the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/advanced#code_example) I followed to implement this, there are no IBOutlet in the code but only linked inside the .xib file.

How can I correctly do this ?

Comment: Did you notice you are passing `nil` as the owner?

Comment: I don't, I'm new to swift . where it is nil ?

Comment: The part that says `owner: nil`.

Comment: In the google documentation I provided, the owner is nil here

Comment: They are obviously not connecting outlets to the owner, they are connecting them to the ad view itself. Don't just blindly copy code, you have to understand it first.

Comment: Please how I am suppose to do this ? If I'm not binding anything I'm getting this error ```swift:24: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value``` : ```(nativeAdView.headlineView as! UILabel)```  NativeAdView object has no subview

Comment: In the xib, in the navigator, you are supposed to connect outlets to "Native Ad View". You are connecting them to the owner. Ignore the source code, don't drag the outlets to the source codes. Connect "Media View" with the outlets in its parent "Native Ad View". "Alt+click" the "Native Ad view" and you should see the list of outlets to connect.

Comment: I had the same issue with my Flutter project, the header file was missing so it is impossible to bind outlets to the Native Ad View. the Outlet section is simply missing when you Alt+click :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have the `GADNativeAd` header file in your Runner folder.

To create the header file, simply right click on the Runner folder => new File... and then choose Header.

Name it `GADNativeAd` and copy the code below inside. You will now be able to bind your outlets.

```
//
//  GADNativeAd.h
//  Google Mobile Ads SDK
//
//  Copyright 2017 Google LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADAdChoicesView.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADAdLoaderDelegate.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADAdValue.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADMediaContent.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADMediaView.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADMuteThisAdReason.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADNativeAdAssetIdentifiers.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADNativeAdDelegate.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADNativeAdImage.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADResponseInfo.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADVideoController.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/// Native ad. To request this ad type, pass kGADAdLoaderAdTypeNative
/// (see GADAdLoaderAdTypes.h) to the |adTypes| parameter in GADAdLoader's initializer method. If
/// you request this ad type, your delegate must conform to the GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate
/// protocol.
@interface GADNativeAd : NSObject

#pragma mark - Must be displayed if available

/// Headline.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *headline;

#pragma mark - Recommended to display

/// Text that encourages user to take some action with the ad. For example "Install".
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *callToAction;
/// Icon image.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong, nullable) GADNativeAdImage *icon;
/// Description.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *body;
/// Array of GADNativeAdImage objects.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong, nullable) NSArray<GADNativeAdImage *> *images;
/// App store rating (0 to 5).
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSDecimalNumber *starRating;
/// The app store name. For example, "App Store".
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *store;
/// String representation of the app's price.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *price;
/// Identifies the advertiser. For example, the advertiser’s name or visible URL.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSString *advertiser;
/// Media content. Set the associated media view's mediaContent property to this object to display
/// this content.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nonnull) GADMediaContent *mediaContent;

#pragma mark - Other properties

/// Optional delegate to receive state change notifications.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) id<GADNativeAdDelegate> delegate;

/// Reference to a root view controller that is used by the ad to present full screen content after
/// the user interacts with the ad. The root view controller is most commonly the view controller
/// displaying the ad.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) UIViewController *rootViewController;

/// Dictionary of assets which aren't processed by the receiver.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy, nullable) NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *extraAssets;

/// Information about the ad response that returned the ad.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nonnull) GADResponseInfo *responseInfo;

/// Called when the ad is estimated to have earned money. Available for allowlisted accounts only.
@property(nonatomic, nullable, copy) GADPaidEventHandler paidEventHandler;

/// Indicates whether custom Mute This Ad is available for the native ad.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isCustomMuteThisAdAvailable) BOOL customMuteThisAdAvailable;

/// An array of Mute This Ad reasons used to render customized mute ad survey. Use this array to
/// implement your own Mute This Ad feature only when customMuteThisAdAvailable is YES.
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nullable) NSArray<GADMuteThisAdReason *> *muteThisAdReasons;

/// Registers ad view, clickable asset views, and nonclickable asset views with this native ad.
/// Media view shouldn't be registered as clickable.
/// @param clickableAssetViews Dictionary of asset views that are clickable, keyed by asset IDs.
/// @param nonclickableAssetViews Dictionary of asset views that are not clickable, keyed by asset
///        IDs.
- (void)registerAdView:(nonnull UIView *)adView
       clickableAssetViews:
           (nonnull NSDictionary<GADNativeAssetIdentifier, UIView *> *)clickableAssetViews
    nonclickableAssetViews:
        (nonnull NSDictionary<GADNativeAssetIdentifier, UIView *> *)nonclickableAssetViews;

/// Unregisters ad view from this native ad. The corresponding asset views will also be
/// unregistered.
- (void)unregisterAdView;

/// Reports the mute event with the mute reason selected by user. Use nil if no reason was selected.
/// Call this method only if customMuteThisAdAvailable is YES.
- (void)muteThisAdWithReason:(nullable GADMuteThisAdReason *)reason;

@end

#pragma mark - Protocol and constants

/// The delegate of a GADAdLoader object implements this protocol to receive GADNativeAd ads.
@protocol GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate <GADAdLoaderDelegate>
/// Called when a native ad is received.
- (void)adLoader:(nonnull GADAdLoader *)adLoader didReceiveNativeAd:(nonnull GADNativeAd *)nativeAd;
@end

#pragma mark - Unified Native Ad View

/// Base class for native ad views. Your native ad view must be a subclass of this class and must
/// call superclass methods for all overridden methods.
@interface GADNativeAdView : UIView

/// This property must point to the native ad object rendered by this ad view.
@property(nonatomic, strong, nullable) GADNativeAd *nativeAd;

/// Weak reference to your ad view's headline asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *headlineView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's call to action asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *callToActionView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's icon asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *iconView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's body asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *bodyView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's store asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *storeView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's price asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *priceView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's image asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *imageView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's star rating asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *starRatingView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's advertiser asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet UIView *advertiserView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's media asset view.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet GADMediaView *mediaView;
/// Weak reference to your ad view's AdChoices view. Must set adChoicesView before setting
/// nativeAd, otherwise AdChoices will be rendered according to the preferredAdChoicesPosition
/// defined in GADNativeAdViewAdOptions.
@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) IBOutlet GADAdChoicesView *adChoicesView;

@end
```